# complex series summation up to infinity

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Sum  of series 
>   $$S(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}+\frac{2x}{1+x^2}+\frac{3x^2}{1+x^3}+\frac{4x^3}{1+x^4}+\cdots , |x|<1$$

What I tried.

Let $$A=\ln\bigg[(1+x)(1+x^2)(1+x^3)(1+x^4)\cdots \cdots \bigg]$$

$$A = \ln\bigg[(1+x+x^2+2x^3+2x^4+3x^5+\cdots+ )\bigg]$$

How do is solve it help me please

Comment: With "complex", do you imply that $x \in \mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that such sum has a "closed form".
Note that
$$x\cdot S(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^k}{1+x^{k}}
=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^k}{1-x^{k}}-2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{kx^{2k}}{1-x^{2k}}\\=F(x)-2F(x^2)$$
is the generating function of the sum of odd divisors of $k$ (see [A000593](https://oeis.org/A000593)), where 
$$F(x)=\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}x^{k}\sum_{d|k}d
=\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}d\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}(x^{d})^j=
\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\frac{dx^{d}}{1-x^{d}}$$
is the generating function of the sum of all positive divisors of $k$ (see [A000203](https://oeis.org/A000203))

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the relationship with the $A$ term

$$
S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{g_k'(x)}{g_k(x)} = \frac{d}{dx}\sum_{k=1}^n\ln g_k(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\ln\prod_{k=1}^ng_k(x) = \frac{d}{dx}A 
$$

here $g_k(x) = 1+x^k$.  Also $\prod_{k=1}^n g_k(x) = \frac 12(-1;x)_{n+1}$  ([see](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol)) and

$$
S_n(x) = \frac{d}{dx}\ln\left(\frac 12(-1;x)_{n+1}\right)
$$